# Can't change visibility or close form in Event

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

I'm using the RegistryMonitor wrapper-class from Codeproject to track Registry key changes and this works fine.

But i want to close my form or set an component (groupbox) to invisble when the event is fired.

But that doesn't work  and the code after `groupbox1.visible = false;` or  `this.close();`  won't be executed...

Here are some code snippets:

```
static RegistryMonitor registryMonitor;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string key = @"REGISTRYKEYTOTRACK"
    registryMonitor = new RegistryMonitor(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, key);
    registryMonitor.RegChanged += new EventHandler(OnRegChanged);
    registryMonitor.RegChangeNotifyFilter = RegChangeNotifyFilter.Value;
    registryMonitor.Start();
    groupBox1.Visible = true;
}

private void OnRegChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("before"); //this executes
    groupBox1.Visible = false; //this doesn't work
    MessageBox.Show("after"); // this doesn't execute
    registryMonitor.Stop();
    registryMonitor.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through with a breakpoint?

Comment: Have you click OK to close messagebox `before`? because after closing the message other lines will be execute

Comment: Sure, i clicked the Messagebox  and after that, nothing happens. Even without messagebox it won't work.

Comment: Could be as simple as a missing `Invoke`: `this.Invoke(((Action)() => groupBox1.Visible = false));`.

Comment: That did the trick,  I'm quite new in C# programming, could you explain why i actually need the Invoke?  Your syntax was wrong:  'this.Invoke(new Action(() => { groupBox1.Visible = false; }));'

Comment: As stated in the [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC):  "...the monitoring is hosted in a different thread."  Thus, you need to use [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to marshal your call from that background thread onto the UI thread, where your `groupBox1` lives.  I expect that had you wrapped that code in a `try-catch`, you would have seen an `InvalidOperationException` thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If it is WPF then try this

```
groupBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: It's a C# Windows Forms  Application. (.Net Framework 4.5)

Answer (score 0):

Use the opacity property:

```
groupBox1.Opacity=0;
```

and when you would like to show it:

```
groupBox1.Opacity=1
```